# git pull vs git pull --rebase when trying to git push

Tags: git

I feel that git pull --rebase is a better thing to do when the local repository is not pointing
 to the tip of the current branch. In this case, when we try to do git push, it throws an error saying 
 we should do "git pull". My question is "Isn't a good idea to tell user to use `git pull --rebase"`
 when they are trying to push when their repository isn't pointing to the tip.

Comment: Rebase by default is not a good idea: it can lead to the state of repository you did not intend to have, yet without any merge conflicts. My personal is `git fetch` + `git merge`, all explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git pull` is a shortcut for `git fetch` and then `git merge`. `git pull --rebase` replaces `git merge` with `git rebase`. So to understand the message you when you do `git push` requires understanding what `git rebase` does. In short, this command copies the commits of your current branch that are not on the branch that you are pulling and rewrites them on top of that branch. This means that your branch after `git pull --rebase` has a different history than the current state it is in on the remote. To properly update your remote, you should do `git push -f` which will force your current branch to overwrite the remote one.

**WARNING**

Doing `git push -f` is dangerous since it overwrites the remote branch. If anyone else is working on that same branch, they will have a local copy with the old commits. They will then same error you see when they do `git push`. Only force push when you are the only person working on a branch.

For more details about rebasing, I suggest that you check out the man pages with `git help rebase`.

Comment: If you see the graph using gitk, you will see a lot of merge which is not really a merge but a commit. Since the user hasn't done git pull --rebase all their commit appears as the merge rather than commits.

Comment: "you will see a lot of merge which is not really a merge but a commit." I don't understand what you mean. A merge is a commit.